Why doesn't glmnet handle missing data the way lm does?
Computationally in R, I had some toy data, and I tried to fit an elastic net model using glmnet. I noticed that even if there was just a single missing value, the algorithm would not execute and it's advised to impute the missing value before hand.
# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Generate a 100x5 matrix of random numbers
data_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(100*5), nrow=100, ncol=5)
data_df <- as.data.frame(data_matrix)
data_df[1:1, 3] <- NA # Single missing value
# Generate a vector Y with 100 observations, each being 1, 2, or 3
Y <- sample(1:3, 100, replace=TRUE)
glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(data_df),
                           y = as.matrix(Y),
                           alpha = 0.5,
                           family = "multinomial")
Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda,  : 
  x has missing values; consider using makeX() to impute them

Algorithmically, what's causing elastic net not to fit when there's missing values? In contrast, when using lm and there's a missing value,
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,NA)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)

The code ran without any errors.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Is there a reason you would expect something other than an error when you tell the computer to add, subtract, multiply, and divide some numbers and then don't tell it all of the numbers?

For example, using lm, it seems to automatically handle missing data (not sure how, perhaps by excluding them by default)? But that doesn't seem to be the case with glmnet. Asking from a R code computational perspective.

The way that lm "handles" missing data is that it uses list-wise deletion -- the only cases that are retained & used to estimate the model are the ones for which all of the values in the formula are non-missing. This is not transparent because it's not obvious that lm is deleting the rows with missing values silently, so my opinion is that the lm behavior is not the desired result and glmnet's behavior -- raising an error when the data contains missing values -- is the desired result.

Thank you. I modified my original post if you'd like to post your comment as answer

The way that lm "handles" missing data is that it uses list-wise deletion -- the only cases that are retained & used to estimate the model are the ones for which all of the values in the formula are non-missing.
If you run the code for lm in OP's post, then summary(lm.D9) prints an output that includes this line:

Residual standard error: 0.716 on 17 degrees of freedom
(1 observation deleted due to missingness)

And this line is buried in the middle of the output, so it's easy to overlook. And if we change the data to
ctl <- c(4.17, rep(NA,9))
then the message printed says

Residual standard error: 0.7937 on 9 degrees of freedom
(9 observations deleted due to missingness)

In other words, even though nearly all of the data in ctrl is missing, there's only the faintest clue to that fact printed by summary.
Design
My opinion is that silently deleting data from the input is a bad design, because users may think that they're carrying out an analysis of all of the data that they give to lm, but in fact lm is only analyzing the complete cases (and silently deleting the rest).
Furthermore,glmnet's behavior -- raising an error when the data contains missing values -- is the preferred outcome, because it clearly communicates what happened and why. Even if the user intends to delete the cases with missing data, then there is a simple path to do so: filter the data first and pass only the complete data to glmnet. But the glmnet message is transparent about where the problem lies, and puts the user in the position of deciding how to solve it. By contrary, lm is guessing what the user is trying to do and making a “best effort.”

You can easily change the lm behaviour. You can even do so globally by changing an option in R. I suspect the current default is a legacy from S.

@Roland These facts seem irrelevant. Carrying over a bad design from older software doesn’t make it better, and even if you can change the default bad behavior to be better, the fact remains that the default is still bad.

It doesn't make it better but explains it. Breaking changes in a core function is not something to be taken lightly. Also, this bad default (agreeing with you here) seems to be in many software implementations of OLS regressions. I believe SAS has the same default as R there. On the other hand, a user should always inspect their data before fitting a regression model.

It’s somewhat inconsistant that you think that a user should always inspect their data on the one hand, but should not be explicit about what subset of that data is used in analysis on the other. SAS having poor design is a sorry excuse for R doing the same. Backwards compatibility is not a sufficient reason because R has breaking changes to S all over the place. S itself is almost 50 years old, and humans have learned a lot about software design since then. I think it’s high time to make good software, instead of excuses.

R is both a programming language and an interactive statistics package. I concur that for the programming language the more explicit variant is to be preferred. For interactive analysis on the REPL I like that lm does analyze with little code but advertise what it has done. YMMV

@Bernhard Sure, you can use R interactively, but I don't think that's a great practice. Analysis results are more than the model predictions or coefficient estimates or whatever -- it's also the sequence of steps that you took to obtain that output. Using R in interactive mode introduces the risk that you can't exactly reproduce the sequence of steps that produced the output (because the session history gets lost or erased, etc). Writing scripts and version controlling them creates repeatable processes, audit trails, etc. to exactly reproduce and record what you did to analyze the data.
